# Getting JWT data in Gorilla CustomLoggingHandler

Tags: go, logging, jwt, gorilla

I am using a custom logging handler in my Go web server like this:

```
func main() {
    // ... Set up everything

    router = mux.NewRouter()
    router.Handle("/apilookup",
        raven.Recoverer(
            jwtMiddleware.Handler(
                http.HandlerFunc(
                    doApiLookup)))).Methods("GET")

    loggedRouter := handlers.CustomLoggingHandler(os.Stdout, router, writeLog)

    http.ListenAndServe(listenAddr, loggedRouter)
}
```

In the `writeLog` function, I have made my own version of the Gorilla `handlers.LoggingHandler`, which logs a lot of additional information.

One thing I would like to do is log the user for authenticated requests. Users authenticate to this server using `JWT` (using the `Authorization: Bearer ...` header). I am using Auth0's [`go-jwt-middleware`](https://github.com/auth0/go-jwt-middleware) to parse the token and set its value in the Request's context.

I tried to log the user's email address (one of the claims in the JWT) like this, based on the middleware's documentation:

```
func writeLog(writer io.Writer, params handlers.LogFormatterParams) {

    // ... SNIP

    // If we can't identify the user
    username := "-"

    if userJwt := params.Request.Context().Value("user"); userJwt != nil {
        claims := userJwt.(*jwt.Token).Claims.(*jwtClaims)
        username = claims.Email
    }

    // ... SNIP
}
```

The problem is that `username` is always the initial value `-` and not the expected value from the JWT.

By adding `log.Printf("%+v\n", params.Request.Context())` above the `if`, I see that the `context` doesn't actually contain the parsed JWT data here.

As far as I can tell, the reason this is not working is because the middleware creates a new `Request` with the updated context, so only middleware further down the chain can see it. Because the logging middleware is above the JWT middleware, it does not have that same context.

I know that I can re-parse the JWT in the logging handler (because I do have access to all the headers), but that seems like a lot of overhead for logging.

Is there a better way to do this that will allow me to have access to this data where I want it?